# The definition of "next two weeks"

Tags: meaning

When someone says something like "I will be gone for the next two weeks," do they mean the next two weeks starting next Monday or the next two weeks from today (today is Thursday). Are the words for each meaning or are they used interchangeably?

Comment: Context dependent, but the usual assumption would be that the two week interval starts tomorrow.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, okay. I read it as "the next two weeks that will follow this present week". Since today is Thursday and the present week will not be over until Monday, when the next week begins.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the context.

Comment: I would interpret that to mean a period of two weeks beginning immediately, where *immediately* is context dependent; it might be as soon as I am done telling you this or tonight or tomorrow.